# Исключение нарушение прав доступа при исполнении по адресу 0x00000000

Tags: c++

Задача - реализовать механизм позднего связывания и единый интерфейс при помощи виртуальных функций. Т.е. у нас есть базовый класс, (в моем случае - element) и два производных класса, element_metall и element_nemetall. В производных классах есть свои дополнительные поля: для элементов-металлов это hardness и melting_temp, а для неметаллов - solubility. Для обработки (вывода на экран, записи в файл и чтения из файла) этих полей производных классов я использовал виртуальные функции.

**Вот код классов:**

```
#ifndef Elements_H
#define Elements_H
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;

class element {
protected:
    string name;
    string symbol;
    int number;
    string type;
    float mass;
    string electrons;
public:
    element() : name(""), symbol(""), number(0), type(""), mass(0), electrons("") {};
    virtual void read_from(ifstream &file); //Чтение информации об элементе из файла
    virtual void write_to(ofstream &file); //Запись информации об элементе в файл
    virtual void display(); //Вывод информации об элементе на экран
    float get_mass();
    string get_type();
    string get_name();
};

class element_metall : public element {
private:
    float hardness;
    float melting_temp;
public:
    virtual void read_from(ifstream &file); //Чтение информации об элементе из файла
    virtual void write_to(ofstream &file); //Запись информации об элементе в файл
    virtual void display();
    float get_hardness();
    float get_melting_temp();
};

class element_nemetall : public element {
private:
    float solubility;
public:
    virtual void read_from(ifstream &file); //Чтение информации об элементе из файла
    virtual void write_to(ofstream &file); //Запись информации об элементе в файл
    virtual void display();
    float get_solubility();
};
#endif
```

**Вот реализация методов базового класса:**

```
//ФУНКЦИИ БАЗОВОГО КЛАССА

//Функция вывода информации об 1-ом элементе на экран
void element::display() {
    cout << "\n==================================\n";
    cout << " Название: " << name << endl;
    cout << " Символ: " << symbol << endl;
    cout << " Номер: " << number << endl;
    cout << " Тип: " << type << endl;
    cout << " Масса: " << mass << endl;
    cout << " Эл. конфигурация: " << electrons << endl;
}

//Функция чтения информации об 1-ом элементе из файла
void element::read_from(ifstream &file) {
    file >> name;
    file >> symbol;
    file >> number;
    file >> type;
    file >> mass;
    file >> electrons;
}

//Функция записи информации об 1-ом элементе в файл
void element::write_to(ofstream &file) {
    file << name << " ";
    file << symbol << " ";
    file << number << " ";
    file << type << " ";
    file << mass << " ";
    file << electrons << "";
}

float element::get_mass() {
    return mass;
}

string element::get_type() {
    return type;
}

string element::get_name() {
    return name;
}

//МЕТОДЫ МЕТАЛЛОВ

void element_metall::display() {
    element::display();
    cout << " Плотность: " << hardness << endl;
    cout << " Температура плавления: " << melting_temp << endl;
}

void element_metall::read_from(ifstream &file) {
    element::read_from(file);
    file >> hardness;
    file >> melting_temp;
}

void element_metall::write_to(ofstream &file) {
    element::write_to(file);
    file << hardness << " ";
    file << melting_temp << endl;
}

float element_metall::get_hardness() {
    return hardness;
}

float element_metall::get_melting_temp() {
    return melting_temp;
}

//МЕТОДЫ НЕМЕТАЛЛОВ

void element_nemetall::display() {
    element::display();
    cout << " Эл. конфигурация: " << electrons << endl;
    cout << " Растворимость: " << solubility << endl;
}

void element_nemetall::read_from(ifstream &file) {
    element::read_from(file);
    file >> solubility;
}

void element_nemetall::write_to(ofstream &file) {
    element::write_to(file);
    file << solubility << endl;
}

float element_nemetall::get_solubility() {
    return solubility;
}
```

**Вот класс-контейнер:**

```
#ifndef ChymTable_H
#define ChymTable_H
#include "Elements.h"
#include "Elements.cpp"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class ChymTable {
private:
    int max_num_elements;
    int num_elements;
    element **pt_elements;
public:
    ChymTable(unsigned int max_elements);
    ~ChymTable();

    virtual void add_element(element aelement);
    void add_nemetall(element_nemetall anemetall);
    void read_elements_from_file(string filename);
    void write_elements_to_file(string filename);
    void display_all_elements();
    void find_element_by_mass(float amass);
};
#endif
```

**Вот реализация класса-контейнера:**

```
#include "ChymTable.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

//Конструктор класса-контейнера
ChymTable::ChymTable(unsigned int max_elements) {
    max_num_elements = max_elements;

    pt_elements = new element*[max_num_elements];
    num_elements = 0;

    cout << "\nВызван конструктор класса ChymTable.";
    cout << "\n --- выделено объектов: " << max_num_elements;
    cout << "\n --- загружено элементов: " << num_elements << endl;
}

//Деструктор класса-контейнера
ChymTable::~ChymTable() {
    delete[] pt_elements;
    max_num_elements = 0;
    num_elements = 0;
    cout << "\nВызван деструктор класса ChymTable.\nВыделенная память освобождена." << endl;
}

void ChymTable::add_element(element aelement) {
    if (num_elements < max_num_elements) {
        pt_elements[num_elements] = &aelement;
        num_elements++;
    }
}

void ChymTable::read_elements_from_file(string filename) {
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(filename);
    if (!infile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Файл с данным именем не найден!" << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    int N;
    infile >> N;
    infile.get();

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        element new_element;
        new_element.read_from(infile);
        add_element(new_element);
    }
    infile.close();

    cout << "Загружены элементы из файла " << filename << ".";
    cout << "\n --- число загруженных элементов: " << num_elements << endl;
};

void ChymTable::write_elements_to_file(string filename) {
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open(filename);

    outfile << num_elements << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) {
        pt_elements[i]->write_to(outfile);
    }
    outfile.close();

    cout << "Элемнеты записаны в файл " << filename << ".";
    cout << "\n --- число записанных элементов: " << num_elements;
}

void ChymTable::display_all_elements() {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) {
        pt_elements[i]->display();
    }
}

void ChymTable::find_element_by_mass(float amass) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) {
        if (pt_elements[i]->get_mass() == amass) {
            cout << "\n\nЭлемент с введенной атомной массой найден!" << endl;
            pt_elements[i]->display();
        }
    }
}
```

Ошибка возникает в реализации класса-контейнера, при попытке вызова функции `display_all_elements()`.
**Ошибка: "Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00000000 в Lab6.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при исполнении по адресу 0x00000000."**

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему! Я не знаю в чем дело, может с указателями что напутал? Помогите

Answer (score 1):

Фундаментальная ошибка, которая проходит через весь код, это

```
void ChymTable::add_element(element aelement) {
    if (num_elements < max_num_elements) {
        pt_elements[num_elements] = &aelement;
        num_elements++;
    }
}
```

Здесь вы запоминаете в вашем массиве указатель на локальную переменную `aelement`. Эта локальная переменная будет уничтожена сразу после выхода из функции `add_element`, а ваш указатель останется указывать "в никуда".

Если вы хотите хранить в своем массива *указатели* на элементы, то позаботьтесь о том, чтобы сами элементы жили так же долго, как и указатели. Иначе получится ерунда.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Я уже пол года не программировал, всё забыл, поэтому не понимаю, как сделать, чтобы элементы "жили долго"... Сделать их глобальными? Извините за тупые вопросы, но я правда всё забыл...

Comment: @Nikort В рамках вашей постановки задачи элементы придется выделять динамически.

Comment: Так я вроде бы так и делаю в конструкторе класса-контейнера 'pt_elements = new element*[max_num_elements];'...

Comment: @Nikort Это создание массива *указателей* на элементы. Сами элементы тут не создаются. Я же веду речь именно о создании самих элементов, т.е. объектов element_metall и element_nemetall

Comment: Вот так получается? `pt_elements[num_elements] = new element` 
Я просто уже всё забыл, даже не могу вспомнить как память правильно выделять...

Comment: Сейчас, кстати, в консоль вывелись значения, только везде нули, получается файл прочитался не правильно? Или ещё где-то нужно изменения внести?

Answer (score 0):

```
pt_elements[i]->display();
```

В этой строке поле display нулевое, вы пытаетесь передать управление на нулевой адрес. Теперь отладчик в руки и смотрите где оное поле изменяется и почему.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, еще бы знать как пользоваться отладчиком... Был бы рад, если бы вы помогли поконкретнее разобраться...

Comment: @Nikort начните с простейших примеров типа Hello World и справки по отладчику из Студии. Писать что-то сложнее трех строк без освоения отладчика все равно не имеет смысла. Буду конкретные вопросы по отладке - задавайте.

Comment: Вот что выдает отладчик (скриншот): http://pastenow.ru/82fd58e7d3dfe4340efe8e1f8fd9f394

Comment: Немного подразобрался с отладчиком. Выяснилось, что элементы считываются из файла правильно, но в объект класса-контейнера записываются неверно: туда попадают непонятные символы, нули и прочий бред... Вы не подскажите, почему так происходит или как это узнать?